# javascript to get the ID of an input under a label with some conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wanted to seek some help regarding on getting ID of the input which is = "layout_input_toc16"

filtering with these following conditions:

-label class = "current"

-input type="radio"

-input name = "onswipe_options[toc_layout]"

```
<label class="current">
<input type="radio" name="onswipe_options[toc_layout]" class="option-16; ?>" value="16" id="layout_input_toc16">
<img src="http://cdn.onswipe.com/reader/raw/lay/toc/16/_l-medium.png" alt="16" title=""  width="220" height="165">
<p class="name">Toulouse</p>
</label>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: FWIW, you have invalid (and downright odd-looking) class names in `class="option-16; ?>"`

Comment: `$('label.current :radio[name="onswipe_options\\[toc_layout\\]"]').prop('id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('.current input[type="radio"][name="onswipe_options[toc_layout]"]').attr('id');
```